# "BuildChildCallback" structure in source code

Tags: c#, generics

I am reading the book ".NET Domain-Driven Design With C#", written by Tim MacCarthy, and there is a structure that I cannot understand. Can you explain?

Here is a method:

```
protected override void BuildChildCallbacks()
{
    this.ChildCallbacks.Add("addresses",
        delegate(Company company, object childKeyName)
        {
            this.AppendAddresses(company);
        });
}
```

Here is the *ChildCallbacks* property

```
private Dictionary<string, AppendChildData> childCallbacks;

protected Dictionary<string, AppendChildData> ChildCallbacks
{
    get { return this.childCallbacks; }
}
```

Here is the *AppendChildData* delegate

```
/// <summary>
/// The delegate signature required for callback methods
/// </summary>
/// <param name="entityAggregate"></param>
/// <param name="childEntityKey"></param>
public delegate void AppendChildData(T entityAggregate, object childEntityKeyValue);
```

Comment: What exactly you cannot understand ?

Comment: what is the purpose of the method : "BuildChildCallbacks"

Comment: It adds an item to the `childCallbacks` dictionary..? (that's what the `ChildCallbacks.Add()` method does, which is the only thing the method does)

Comment: Let's start with more general, what is the term "callback" means at that context?

Comment: I believe, that it is just an example in the book how to fill in ChildCallbacks with elements.

Comment: Rufus, I think it is clear from the source code.

Comment: @tahasozgen I agree, but your question is not clear...you've dumped some code and asked "can you explain?" A quick google search will reveal what [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) and [delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) are.

Comment: Okey, I will support more details.